# How to train a model on a cluster with multiple GPUs (single node)

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, multi-gpu

I wish to train a model on a multiple-GPUs, 1-Node cluster on AML (Azure ML).
I have my cluster (STANDARD_ND40RS_V2, which has 8 V100)
I have my Dataset, my Environment (docker), and my script.

When trying to run the script as a pipeline stage, I was expecting to run the script only once, create the relevant batches, and then each GPU of the 8 will get a single one in parallel.
I have some prints in the main script, but when looking at the log file created by AML, these prints were run 8 times for some reason, instead of only once. It seems like the entire script is run each time instead of only once.

This is the code I used:

```
    script_step = PythonScriptStep(
        name=stage_name,
        script_name=stage_script.py,
        source_directory=self.project_root_path,
        arguments=arguments,
        inputs=data_inputs,
        outputs=[self.data_outputs[stage_name]],
        compute_target=compute_target,
        runconfig=runconfig,
        allow_reuse=True
    )
    pipeline_steps.append(script_step)
    pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=self.ws, steps=pipeline_steps)
    experiment = Experiment(self.ws, self.experiment_name)
    pipeline_run = experiment.submit(pipeline, tags=self.experiment_tag)
```

This is the script stage_script.py:

```
 def run_script_stage(input_ds, output_ds, args):
     input_ls, output_ls = print_stage_input_output(input_ds, output_ds, args)
     params = json.loads(args.params)
     print (f"params: {params}")
     # some lines for accessing the data from the blob, and other lines for training the model
```

The only thing that does run only once, is the training process.
So what is happening here?
How should I use a multi GPU instance for training in a pipeline?